# Are open sets locally simplicial?

Tags: convex-analysis

So I read parts of Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis".

When introducing "locally simplicial" sets, all the examples stated are convex sets, yet he mentions that they do not need to be convex.

I wonder whether all open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are locally simplicial? I think such a fact would have been included in the reference if it were true.

My reasoning goes as follows.

A subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is locally simplicial, if for all $x\in S$ there is a finite collection of simplices $\{S_1, \dots, S_m\}$ such that for some neighborhood $U$ of $x$ it holds
$$ U \cap S = U \cap (S_1 \cup \dots \cup S_m).$$

If I assume $S$ to be open, then for every $x$ there is a ball with radius $\epsilon$ around $x$ that is still in $S$.
If I place a single simplex $S_1$ that contains $x$ in its interior into that ball and take $U=S_1 \setminus \partial S_1$, I have that $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and it holds
$$U=U\cap S = U \cap S_1.$$

Comment: You have answered the question in your title by "yes". So what is the purpose of your question?

Comment: I want to know if there is a flaw in my reasoning.

Comment: The finite number of simplices has to *precede* the "for every neighborhood" part. You can't choose a different simplex for each neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: @LasseH. Of course I knew that ;-) My comment intended to motivate you to formulate future question in a better way. (1) Use the additional tag "proof-verification". (2) Make sure that the **text** contains a definite question, for example "Is the following proof / argument correct?" As it is, your post asks a question in the title, but the text does not contain any open question, but answers the question in the title.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I'll take this into account next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Yes, your proof is correct.